# PHP style guide / coding standards: which one to apply?

Tags: php

I am trying to implement and follow some coding standards in my PHP code.

I did read a few question already asked here but I think an attempt to centralise information might help others like me. I found a few resources (6 until now):

- PSR: [PHP Framework Interop Group](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md)
- [Wordpress PHP coding standards](http://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/coding-standards/php/)
- [framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.html](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.html) (I am not
  allowed to post more than 2 links yet)
- [pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.php](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.php)

The latter has a tool to help comply with it, CodeSniffer, although you can configure it to check for any standards.

- [drupal.org/coding-standards](http://drupal.org/coding-standards)
- https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html

Although they do seem to set a common ground, they do show conflicting info, for instance, the first two links, Wordpress recommends to have a space after opening parenthesis and before closing one, while PHP-FIG recommends the opposite: `if ( $a === 0 )` v `if ($a === 0)`

Codeigniter style guide basically contradicts everything in the Wordpress guide...

Are there any other resources that might have a higher authority on the matter?
What are others using, or does it even matter to follow a "standard" if it is contradicted by another?

Comment: are you coming from python?

Comment: Use whatever is easiest to read ... PHP doesn't have significant whitespace as such *shrugs*

Comment: it'd be pointless to use WP standards if you're working on (say) CodeIgniter. But regardless, coding standards are opinions, and asking for opinions is off-topic.

Comment: With codesniffer, you can disable/change individual sniffs you don't want to apply from any coding standard that you use - but if you're working as part of adevelopment team, then every member of the team should be working to the same standard

Comment: Coding standards are generally a vehicle for uniformity across larger projects, and they are almost always opinion-based. The true standards are set within the constraints of the language or framework you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this question is going to get closed because the answers will be opinion based and so is mine:

I would not go by Wordpress, the code of that project is... not good. WP is for sure not popular because of it's "superior" code and architecture. If you want a blog, take it, if you want good examples of development, architecture and best practice - stay far away from it.

PEAR is just outdated IMHO. And it is not just pear that has a code sniffer, phpcs is a generic tool:

https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer

Good projects come with a ruleset for their conventions. The sniffer itself comes bundled with a few rulesets like PEAR and I think PSR as well.

The PSR standard is a pretty good one to use except the never ending tab vs space discussion. I personally think spaces for indention over tabs is idiotic because that's exactly what tabs are thought for and virtually every editor can configure the displayed tab size to match X spaces.

So I would recommend the PSR standard.

But I use whatever standard the project I'm working on is using. If I work on CakePHP I use their coding standard, if I have to work on Wordpress (please no!), I'll use theirs. For my own projects I go for PSR.

I would recommend you to read this book in addition:

[http://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882)

It's using Java for the examples but the language doesn't really matter here.

Whatever standard you use, I'm happy you think about writing clean code and that you want to make sure you have a standard! Many "developers" just don't care and write a huge mess.

Answer (score 3):

Ultimately the way you format your code I think will come down to these questions...

**Who looks at the code? Just you?**
Stick with what you feel comfortable and feels more readable for you. There are very few projects where everyone actually adheres to the full coding standards.

**Will anyone else in the future look at the code?**
If so use the most common standard. You feel comfortable with.

**Are you building/coding off an existing codebase?**
Try to match their existing standards.

I am actually working off the 'ownCloud' core for my current projects. They have this huge guide of how to format their code. NOBODY who contributes follows it. So the code looks horrendous and is so inconsistent. Any portions of code I have to work with I always reformat to my taste since there is no standards police.

Comment: What? If Owncloud accept PRs that don't follow the standard it's not a very well managed project.

Comment: It seems like ownCloud is in this state where they are in the middle of trying to migrate to a new framework (symfony) while keeping a bunch of legacy integrations. However, I cannot guarantee that the PR's are the cause of the inconsistencies, but source from all over the application is just all over the place formatting wise.